# Spray 8 gallons of concrete sealer with plastic cheap sprayer?

Tags: concrete, sealer

I have 1,000 sq. ft of stamped concrete to reseal.   I am planning on buying Armor AR350 sealer (https://www.foundationarmor.com/AR350/) and doing two coats of sprayed coverage.

I would really prefer to not buy a metal sprayer and clean it afterwards and store it for the future in my garage....

If I get a cheap 2 gallon Harbor Freight plastic sprayer (or equivalent at your local big box of choice), will it last through spraying 8 gallons of this material?  (One coat of 4 gallons, wait one hour, and a second coat of 4 gallons).

The alternative seems to me to buy a metal sprayer and clean with Xylene afterwards, but I'm trying to not build up my collection of random sprayers in my garage (I already have a pesticide sprayer backpack).

Comment: Quality control at Horrible Fright is so random that nobody can predict if it will break 30 seconds into the job or last until the year 3000.

Comment: Well, any plastic sprayer...  The Home Depot / Lowes / Harbor Freight $20 special.

Comment: This is a matter of opinion or practical experience. Go read the reviews at the sale sites to see what those who have the practical experience with the ones you're interested in say. As for the opinion based part of whether it'll last or not, opinions are [off-topic here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: How is this an opinion?   If you have tried this once with a cheap plastic sprayer, I suspect it's pretty factual whether the sprayer is going to clog up or not over a few hour span.  I think a concrete guy probably sees this as pretty factual....

Comment: VTC; Best case is any answer would be speculative. I don't see any reason why the cheap sprayer from HF (or whatnot) wouldn't work. Whether it breaks halfway through is anyone's guess.

Comment: If it breaks you go buy another one, who cares. The question is if a BS sprayer will put an acceptable fan spray out of its tip, which is a no. Last time I used one was to put stain sealer on a deck, which then required rolling/ back brushing. **It won't break; the question is *will it work*.** Also, it was oil based and I succeeded in cleaning it with mineral spirits (on the third try). Screw working with xylene. - Which I just redid, and I used **just a roller** (because screw all that noise) and then back brushed.

Comment: It's a "matter of opinion **or practical experience**" which is what we're all here for, right? Mine says **you'll get your 8 gallons and it will *still* work**. IDK about letting it sit for an hour though. That's about exactly how many gallons I went through to do a deck and it *was not* water-soluble. (HD sprayer I think)

Comment: *Can I use a plastic sprayer with oil-based?* Yes. Especially if it's a $20 one you don't care about. ... With xylene? I don't think I'd want to aerosol something that's thinned with that stuff anyway.

Comment: instruction on the 350 suggests that  it's solvent is actone and/or xylene,  so long as your chosen plastic sprayer can withstand that you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I still have the cheap HD sprayer I used to apply Ghostshield to a concrete slab five years ago. It worked great. Ghostshield is water-soluble so this isn't a 100% match, but assuming the substance you plan to use is compatible with the plastic in your sprayer and thin enough, I'd expect it to work just fine.

Comment: Okay cool,  I asked my buddy who is also a epoxy / concrete guy.  I'll post up what he says (he may not want to give away trade secretes though!). I'm on the fence to order a Chapin International 1449, which isn't too expensive and clean it, but it is already such a PITA chore and I hate storing more stuff at my house loaded with chemicals and fumes!

Comment: Concrete buddy says, spring for the upgraded can....  YMMV!

Comment: I used a garden sprayer to apply concrete sealer (sodium silicate?), But that too was a thin water-based solution.m, and basic rather than acidic.

Comment: @Leroy105 - ask what YOU *could* use, not what *they* would use or buy. You're doing 1000sq', *once*. If you use a roller will it look funny? Buddy says upgrade, because it won't applicate correctly out of a crap sprayer, or because you'd have a 'useful' tool afterwards? IDK man, it's $20; try it out on your back sidewalk, not the new stuff. - That Chapin looks nice. I bet it comes out in a real nice fan instead of loading the crap out of the edges after five min of anything going through it like a bs sprayer does. But on stamped concrete does anything really matter? A mop would suffice?

Comment: @Mazura,  I did a test patch with a water sealer and I agree on the Chapin.  My $20 sprayer was really sloppy.  The water sealer I put on a bit thick and uneven and it leveled out and looked nice and you could probably get away with it.   I did another test patch with a solvent mix, and I think it looks a bit nicer.   I think you could   I'm just spraying with the Chapin 1449 today and backrolling it.   Total project is about 6 man hours.  3 hours to clear patio and wash, 3 hours to spray and backroll two coats.  (I got quoted $1700, and material is about $500.  So decent payback on this one.)

Comment: I ended up using a $250/gallon solvent, and laid it on top of a 2 year old water acrylic coat.   I only needed one coat of solvent and used ~4.5 gallons for 1,000 sq. ft.  I did a test patch on the acrylic sealer, to ensure good bond.  I would recommend the Chapin 1449 + Xylene to clean afterwards.  You could probably just roll the material, but it was really fast spraying + backrolling if you can get an assistant.  The Chapin REEKS after using and we couldn't store it in our basement, so it has to live outside in a deck box.  I would not want to store it in my garage, so it is kind of PITA.